# Plot number of tickets opened and closed by month in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, clustered-index

I have a list of tickets and I would to create a graph to show how many opened and closed by month.

Every ticket item has 2 data points: opened_at date and closed_at date. I want to create a clustered Column Graph by month.year.

Every month.year's should display 2 columns: a) quantity of opened_at items and b) quantity of closed at items:

```
Item    opened_at       closed_at
Ticket 1    22/02/2020  
Ticket 2    22/02/2020  
Ticket 3    22/02/2020  22/02/2020
Ticket 4    22/02/2020  
Ticket 5    12/02/2021  
Ticket 6    12/02/2021  11/04/2022
Ticket 7    12/02/2021  
Ticket 8    09/02/2022  
Ticket 9    07/02/2022  
Ticket 10   03/02/2022
```

For the Graph:
by month year example: 01.2022 (Jan 22), 02.2022 (Feb 22), and so on...]

The X-axis should display every month in sequence, and the Y-axis should display the quantity.

I used tably to summarise items by date (by month) and it has been the further I could get.

Comment: Most of the lines in your example don't have 2 data points. Please also format the lines in a sensible way. Currently, it is not clear if you did made a mistake while copying the lines or if your data is messed up.

Comment: This is the case for the read data set. When a ticket has been closed, the "closed_at" field will be populated. If it hasn't, then, it will be blank.

Comment: @Marcelo Bastos how you count the number of tickets if you didn't know the start and end date?